# PowerShell script can't connect to computername when run from C# application

Tags: c#, powershell

When I run the below PowerShell script from my C# application, the PowerShell script can't connect to a remote computer by name. It can test connection with IP address, though. The PowerShell code works when I run it outside of the C# application, and it returns the value "Offline" in the C# application. Can anyone help me with this?

C# Code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;
using System.IO;

namespace ClientCheck
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private string RunScript(string scriptText)
        {
            // create Powershell runspace 
            InitialSessionState initial = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
            Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(initial);
            PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
            ps.Runspace = runspace;
            //Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();

            // open it 
            ps.Runspace.Open();
            ps.Runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("ComputerName", CompnameInput.Text);

            // create a pipeline and feed it the script text 
            Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
            pipeline.Commands.AddScript(scriptText);

            // add an extra command to transform the script output objects into nicely formatted strings 
            // remove this line to get the actual objects that the script returns. For example, the script 
            // "Get-Process" returns a collection of System.Diagnostics.Process instances. 
            pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");

            // execute the script 
            Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();

            // close the runspace 
            ps.Runspace.Close();

            // convert the script result into a single string 
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (PSObject obj in results)
            {
                stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
            }

            // return the results of the script that has 
            // now been converted to text 
            return stringBuilder.ToString();
        }
        // helper method that takes your script path, loads up the script 
        // into a variable, and passes the variable to the RunScript method 
        // that will then execute the contents 
        private string LoadScript(string filename)
        {
            try
            {
                // Create an instance of StreamReader to read from our file. 
                // The using statement also closes the StreamReader. 
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename))
                {

                    // use a string builder to get all our lines from the file 
                    StringBuilder fileContents = new StringBuilder();

                    // string to hold the current line 
                    string curLine;

                    // loop through our file and read each line into our 
                    // stringbuilder as we go along 
                    while ((curLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        // read each line and MAKE SURE YOU ADD BACK THE 
                        // LINEFEED THAT IT THE ReadLine() METHOD STRIPS OFF 
                        fileContents.Append(curLine + "\n");
                    }

                    // call RunScript and pass in our file contents 
                    // converted to a string 
                    return fileContents.ToString();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // Let the user know what went wrong. 
                string errorText = "The file could not be read:";
                errorText += e.Message + "\n";
                return errorText;
            }

        }

        private void Exitbutton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void DeviceStatusButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // run our script and put the result into our textbox 
            // NOTE: make sure to change the path to the correct location of your script
            Testlabel_Out.Content = RunScript(LoadScript(@"C:\VSProjects\ClientChecksNew\ClientChecksNew\Script\Get_Devicestatus.ps1"));
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the PowerShell code:

```bsh
if (Test-Connection $computername -Quiet -Count 1) {
    $devicestatus = "Online"
} else {
    $devicestatus = "Offline"
}
$devicestatus
```

Comment: you should add a `Param()` Section, e.g: `Param($Computername)` at the first line of your ps1 code

Comment: @Avshalom Like this?
param($Computername)
If(Test-Connection $computername -Quiet -Count 1){
    $devicestatus = "Online"
}
Else{
    $devicestatus = "Offline"
}
$devicestatus

If thats the case it does not work, i get the error:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingValidationException' occurred in System.Management.Automation.dll

Comment: I'm sure you must have a good reason for doing it this way, but I have to ask anyway: .Net has a Ping class. It's fast and reliable. Why use PowerShell?

Comment: @crownedjitter - Yes, I will be using more powershell scripts later, with for instance invoke-command. That don't work either and I get this error message when doing that, so it seems that I cant even find the computernames..


An unhandled exception of type 'System.Management.Automation.CmdletInvocationException' occurred in System.Management.Automation.dll

Additional information: One or more computer names are not valid. If you are trying to pass a URI, use the -ConnectionUri parameter, or pass URI objects instead of strings.

Answer (score 0):

I seemed to be my XAML-code that was wrong.. Compname_Input looked like this:

```
<TextBox x:Name="CompnameInput" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="18" Margin="242,14,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="&#xD;&#xA;" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="109" MaxLength="50" MaxLines="1" AutomationProperties.Name="CompNameinput" Tag="" Grid.Row="2"/>
```

No idea how the "Text=" got there, but that was the problem!

Answer (score -1):

You have to add -computername to your powershell script.

```
If(Test-Connection -computername $computername -Quiet -Count 1){
    $devicestatus = "Online"
}
Else{
    $devicestatus = "Offline"
}
$devicestatus
```

Comment: The parameter name is not required. As [documented](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh849808.aspx) `-ComputerName` is defined as the first positional parameter, so `Test-Connection $computername ...` should work just fine.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, exactly :)